# How can i return a promise or wait for require?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

This is for my vuejs+webpack project

How can i return a promise or wait for require to load a file ?

**exmaple :**

```
var myfile= require('./assets/myjson.json') // a big json file
console.log(myfile) //this sometime not printed correctly
```

sometime console.log not print object correctly in console

so i would like to know whether it is possible to return promise like this

```
require('./assets/myjson.json').then(function(){ 
   // big file loaded completetly
   console.log(myfile) 
}
```

i have to process the object after the require callback, i dont find a way to do this

the object is printed in console as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**1. Create a Promise**

```
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // do a thing, possibly async, then…

        if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
            resolve("Stuff worked!");
        }
        else {
            reject(Error("It broke"));
        }
    });
```

**2. Using the Promise**

```
    promise.then(function(result) {
       console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
    }, function(err) {
       console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
    });
```

I hope be useful!